# Groups Catalog 2 module breaks the frontend of my website

Tags: database, sql, error-log

I just installed this module and there's not a whole lot of information out there about it. The admin panel seems to be fine for this module in the configuration.

Here's my stack trace:

There has been an error processing your request

```
SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`status`, `e`.`visibility`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`cost`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`gift_message_available`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`is_recurring`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_title`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`recurring_profile`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`sku_type`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`url_path`, `e`.`visibility`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`ingredient_list`, `e`.`upc`, `e`.`faq`, `e`.`howtoapply`, `e`.`description`, `e`.`video`, `e`.`status`, `e`.`groupscatalog2_groups` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `groupscatalog_product_idx` ON groupscatalog_product_idx.catalog_entity_id=e.entity_id AND groupscatalog_product_idx.group_id='1' A



Trace:
#0 /home/innovis2/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/innovis2/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/innovis2/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.`ent...', Array)
#4 /home/innovis2/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.`ent...', Array)
#5 /home/innovis2/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `e`.`ent...', Array)
#6 /home/innovis2/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(740): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `e`.`ent...', Array)
#7 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1046): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `e`.`ent...')
#8 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(871): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
#9 /home/innovis2/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(752): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
#10 [internal function]: Varien_Data_Collection->count()
#11 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/design/frontend/bizarre/default/template/meigee/meigeewidgetsbizarre/slider.phtml(4): count(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection))
#12 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/innovis2/...')
#13 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/bizarr...')
#14 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#15 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Template/Filter.php(76): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 [internal function]: Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter->widgetDirective(Array)
#18 /home/innovis2/public_html/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php(163): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#19 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(560): Varien_Filter_Template->filter('{{widget t...')
#20 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Page.php(123): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->filter('{{widget t...')
#21 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Cms_Block_Page->_toHtml()
#22 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('cms_page', true)
#24 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Wrapper.php(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('', true, true)
#25 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Wrapper->_toHtml()
#26 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#28 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#30 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/design/frontend/bizarre/innoblinc/template/page/1column.phtml(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#31 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/innovis2/...')
#32 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/bizarr...')
#33 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#34 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#35 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#36 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#37 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#38 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#39 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#40 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#41 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#42 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#43 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#44 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#45 /home/innovis2/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#46 {main}
```

Is the issue with the meigee module or perhaps the innoblinc template #30?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stack trace this line from the slider template loads a product collection and counts the loaded items:

```
#11 /home/innovis2/public_html/app/design/frontend/bizarre/default/template/meigee/meigeewidgetsbizarre/slider.phtml(4): count(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection))
```

Everything below is innocuous, #30 is just the page template that loads the content for the current page.

It looks like an incompatibility between this Meigee module and Groups Catalog: the slider loads the collection in a way that the groups catalog module did not anticipate. I cannot tell you what exactly is wrong based on the stack trace.

But to verify that the issue is actually between these modules, you should first try to disable the slider and see if it's  working.

Comment: Okay, I'll try and disable it now. Thank you @fschmengler

Comment: So after i disabled Meigee the error went away and the front end was loading again. Then I enabled catalog 2 and meigee one more time and there is no error but it gets stuck in a "too many redirects" loop. Any idea?

Comment: No sorry, would need to debug the module by myself

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would be your next step? Also do you use xdebug and with what IDE are you using? @Fabian Schmengler

Comment: I use xdebug and PhpStorm. I would set a breakpoint in the slider template where the collection is loaded (the line from the stacktrace) and inspect `$collection->getSelect()` to see the SQL query, then if it is not obvious already, try it out in the MySQL console to see the error. Then look where the collection is instantiated to see where the error comes from.

Comment: I really want to start using xdebug and PhpStorm, i've heard great things about both in combination with working with magento too. When I ran that sql query from above in sql i got this error message: **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'A LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2**
 
Sorry to keep bugging you, just trying to figure this out.